# Asyncronous Data coming from udp socket into TextBox Simultaneously

Tags: c#, multithreading, asyncsocket, udpclient

I am dealing with socket programming, but i have some issues about threading mechanism. Well, actually this is a big question mark on my head.

Firstly, i have a UDPListener class that i can receive the data coming from some clients on network. Additionally, i put an event handler in that class, i want to invoke a textbox when data is received simultaneously.

```
        class udpListener
        {     
           private static int portNumber = 9081;
           private UdpClient udp = new UdpClient(portNumber);
           private bool isend = false;
           public volatile int CountOfReceived = 0;
           public List<string> messageList = new List<string>();
           public List<string> ipList = new List<string>();
           public bool isClientClosed = false;
           messageReceivedEventArgs mre=new messageReceivedEventArgs();

        public void StartListening()
        {
            udp.BeginReceive(Receive, new object());   //BeginReceive must be completed by calling EndReceive method
        }

        private void Receive(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            if (udp.Client == null)
                return;
            Interlocked.Increment(ref CountOfReceived);

            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portNumber);
            byte[] bytes = udp.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);  //Ends a pending asynchronous receive

            if (bytes.Length > 0)
            {
                mre.isMessageReceived = true;
                mre.message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes); 
            }
            else
                mre.isMessageReceived = false;

            controlMessageReceived();
            string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
            string[] seperator = {"|"};
            string[] array = message.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            messageList.Add(array[0]);
            ipList.Add(ip.Address.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            StartListening();       
        }

        public void closeSocket()
        {
            if (udp.Client != null)
                udp.Close();
        }

        private void controlMessageReceived()
        {
            if(mre.isMessageReceived)
                handler(this,mre);
        }

        public event EventHandler<messageReceivedEventArgs> handler;


    }

    public class messageReceivedEventArgs:EventArgs
    {
        public bool isMessageReceived { get; set; }
        public string message {get;set;}
    }
```

As you can see, when bytes.length bigger than zero, i suppose yes, data is received and now i need to invoke textbox to transfer that data into textbox.

I simply test this scenario with a buttoneventhandler in main thread

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        networkInterface ni = new networkInterface();

        udpSender UDPSender = new udpSender();
        udpListener UDPListener = new udpListener();

        IPAddress braddress = ni.GetBroadcastAddress(ni.GetDefaultGateway(), ni.GetSubnetMask());
        UDPSender.Send(braddress, "somedatahere");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        UDPListener.StartListening();
        UDPListener.handler += appendTextBox;


    }      

    private void appendTextBox(object sender, messageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += e.message;

    }
}
```

I would store those messages into a string list and after socket is closed i would read that data from that listbox, but it is so tricky and unprofessional way to do that, i want to have those data in textbox while they are still received by server. I definetely aware of that my textbox is in main thread and appendtext method belongs to Asyncronous thread, and it is not permitted to access that textbox from another thread, but i really cannot figure out how to do that, what am i supposed to do to obtain what i desire.

Here is the solution how i overcome this problem, thanks to @Troy Mac1ure

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {

    public delegate void UpdateTextCallback(string s);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        networkInterface ni = new networkInterface();

        udpSender UDPSender = new udpSender();
        udpListener UDPListener = new udpListener();

        IPAddress braddress = ni.GetBroadcastAddress(ni.GetDefaultGateway(), ni.GetSubnetMask());
        UDPSender.Send(braddress, "gr|smartrc");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        UDPListener.StartListening();
        UDPListener.handler += appendTextBox;     

    }

    private void appendTextBox(object sender, messageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            textBox1.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(addTextBox), new object[] { e.message });  // invoking itself
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += e.message;
        }      
    }

    private void addTextBox(string text)
    {
        textBox1.Text += text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the update to happen on the main thread by invoking itself. There are a few ways to declare and perform this task. Here is one:

```
public delegate void UpdateTextCallback(object sender, messageReceivedEventArgs e);

private void appendTextBox(object sender, messageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            listBox1.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(appendTextBox), new object[] { sender, e });  // invoking itself
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += e.message;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but i do not understand how it works, firstly my event handler invokes appndTextBox, then another delegate which belongs to main thread try to invoke the textbox, am i right? Additionally, this new delegate type and appendTextBox method doesn't match, after i modified UpdateTextCallback delegate to appendTextBox method type, now i cannot read any data.

Comment: I modified delegating to another method, i added the new solution on my question, now i can read the data, but it is a bit hard to understand, can you please correct me if i am wrong. Firstly, i invoked AppendTextBox from Asyncronous thread with eventhandler, and then in appendTextBox i invoked to another method with a new delegate which is belongs to main method, so there is no crossthread problem, is that true? Additionally, how textbox1.InvokeRequired know if textbox1 is tried to invoke? ı donn exactly understand the concept of it. Finally, i really appreciate for your help.

Comment: InvokeRequired checks to see if the control is being accessed on the originating Thread. If it is not then It calls the function to run on the originating thread, so you actually will have two appendTextBox() functions running at the same time. The first function (running in your new thread) will just exit after calling the second one (running in the original Thread) and the second will update your textbox accordingly.

Comment: I got it now, so my approach to create a new method named addTextBox which is actually called in original thread is true, isn't it?

Comment: That works, but you should have been able to just use appendTextBox(). I had the declaration incorrect for the delegate (answering a little too late at night). See the edited answer for the correct declaration.